# Arduino uno + cnc shield v3 + Stepper Motor Driver A4988 + AccelStepper?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, motor, shields, stepper

I successfully run the [AccelStepper examples](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/examples.html) on an [Arduino Mega](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560) with a [RAMPS 1.4](http://reprap.org/wiki/RAMPS_1.4) shield, two [A4988 stepper motor drivers](https://www.pololu.com/product/1182) and two [17HS16-0284S stepper motors](http://www.omc-stepperonline.com/nema-17-bipolar-stepper-motor-028a-36ncm51ozin-17hs160284s-p-80.html).

I used 3 jumpers on the RAMPS to set the microstep resolution to 1/16.

I used this code inspired by the [Polargraph Server](https://github.com/euphy/polargraph_server_polarshield) for [Polargraph](http://www.polargraph.co.uk/):

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

/* 
// for the Arduino Uno + CNC shield V3

#define MOTOR_A_ENABLE_PIN 8
#define MOTOR_A_STEP_PIN 2
#define MOTOR_A_DIR_PIN 5

#define MOTOR_B_ENABLE_PIN 8
#define MOTOR_B_STEP_PIN 3
#define MOTOR_B_DIR_PIN 6
*/

// for the Arduino Mega + RAMPS 1.4
#define MOTOR_A_ENABLE_PIN 30
#define MOTOR_A_STEP_PIN 36
#define MOTOR_A_DIR_PIN 34

#define MOTOR_B_ENABLE_PIN 56
#define MOTOR_B_STEP_PIN 60
#define MOTOR_B_DIR_PIN 61

AccelStepper motorA(1, MOTOR_A_STEP_PIN, MOTOR_A_DIR_PIN); 
AccelStepper motorB(1, MOTOR_B_STEP_PIN, MOTOR_B_DIR_PIN); 

void setup()
{
  motorA.setEnablePin(MOTOR_A_ENABLE_PIN);
  motorA.setPinsInverted(false, false, true);
  motorB.setEnablePin(MOTOR_B_ENABLE_PIN);
  motorB.setPinsInverted(false, false, true);

  motorA.setAcceleration(100);  
  motorA.move(1000);
  //motorA.setMaxSpeed(100);
  //motorA.setSpeed(100);

  motorB.setAcceleration(100);  
  motorB.move(1000);
  //motorB.setMaxSpeed(100);
  //motorB.setSpeed(100);

  motorA.enableOutputs();
  motorB.enableOutputs();
}

void loop()
{

  motorA.run();
  motorB.run();

}
```

I tried to use the same code with the same stepper motor drivers and motors on a [Arduino Uno](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and a [CNC shield v3](http://blog.protoneer.co.nz/arduino-cnc-shield-v3-00-assembly-guide/) without success (I also used the 3 jumpers to set the microstep resolution to 1/16). The motors do not work and jitter.

What is wrong with my code?

**Bonus questions**:
I have taken this setup and code from the Polargraph server but I didn't get how I'm suppose to know how to use `setEnablePin()` and `setPinsInverted()` methods. In fact, I have troubles finding documentation about the CNC shield V3 and the A4988 drivers (I only found [this page](http://blog.protoneer.co.nz/arduino-cnc-shield-v3-00-assembly-guide/)) to work with AccelStepper.

Comment: I don't know if I solved my problem, but I eventually found out that the Arduino Uno has not enough memory for the code I use to run my motors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually set the ENABLE pins as OUTPUTs, i.e. add in the `setup()` function:

```
pinMode(MOTOR_A_ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT);
pinMode(MOTOR_B_ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT);
```